# Cannot import module projectname.appname when reading CSV

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django project named `localassets` and in turn have an app called `assetlist`.
I have a directory named `scripts` at the root of my project (same level of manage.py) in which I have the following script to read data from a csv:

**load_csv.py**

```
import csv

from localassets.assetlist.models import BusinessUnit, Branch


def run():
    with open('scripts/testing_import.csv') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:

            print(row)
            bu_csv = row[0]
            bu = BusinessUnit.objects.get(bu=bu_csv)
            branch_csv = row[1]
            branch = Branch.objects.get(bu=bu, location_code=branch_csv)

            print(bu, branch)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'assetlist.apps.AssetlistConfig',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_filters',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_bootstrap_icons',
    'django_extensions',
]
```

**assetlist\apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AssetlistConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'assetlist'
```

When attempting to run the script through the command line in my environment using the following command: `python manage.py runscript load_csv` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'localassets.assetlist'
Cannot import module 'scripts.load_csv': No module named 'localassets.assetlist'.
No (valid) module for script 'load_csv' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3
CommandError: An error has occurred running scripts. See errors above.
```

I have re-run migrations and it has resolved successfully but I am unable to get the load_csv script to import my Models. I am unsure as to why this will not run.

**UPDATE:** Including folder structure

[image]

Comment: `from localassets.assetlist.models import BusinessUnit, Branch` should be `from assetlist.models import BusinessUnit, Branch` as `localassets` is the project root folder and not a project package

Comment: @sudden_appearance If I change the import to your suggestion I get an `unresolved reference` for the import. I have updated the question to include my current folder structure of the project.

Comment: Do you get that unresolved reference inside PyCharm? Did you try to run the command? You can mark `localassets` directory as Source Root to get rid of the unresolved reference inside PyCharm

Comment: @DeclanMorgan Can you provide the exact error message you get for the import htat sudden_appearance suggests? It seems like that ought to work.

Comment: @sudden_appearance
@NickODell Within PyCharm I get an Unresolved reference for each 'Model' name but don't get an unresolved reference for the `from assetlist.models`. After ignoring the errors on the actual model names the script successfully runs. Thanks guys!